# How to create a simple json template to send body data with restassured?

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

So i am trying to build a json to send data to the body of my restassured request, like this structure here:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "duch"
  },
  "name": "benny",
  "photoUrls": [
    "string"
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "status": "available"
}
```

So it is as simple as to copy this as string to the body of the request and i am done, i don't want that at all.

Is there a framework of sorts to give this structure and to change the data dynamically somehow? 
I don't want this: (for example)

```
given().body("{\r\n\"city\": \"Hod Hasharon\",\r\n\"description\": \"Automation Hotel\",\r\n\"name\":\"Nir Great hotel\",\r\n\"rating\":5\r\n}")
                    .when().post("http://localhost:8090/example/v1/hotels").then().statusCode(201);
```

I want to be more flexible here, to reference some kind of object (A template with the option to change the data in some places?) that handles this stuff, is there something like that?

Comment: Did you mean to tag [java] or [javascript]?

Comment: Java, i am using rest-assured to do API testing of sorts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is using POJO and Jackson to serialize it to json.

```
public class Payload {

   private int id;
   private String name;
   private List<Tag> tags; //Tag is another class you need to create the same way

   //getters, setters
}
```

And then using objects as payload in your request:

```
Payload payload = new Payload();
payload.setId(123);
payload.setName("John");

given().contentType("application/json").body(payload).when().post("http://example.com");
```

Also don't forget to add [jackson-databind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8) dependency to your project.

There's more about that in official documentation here: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#object-mapping

Comment: if using Google Gson, then make a small change as follows 
`given().contentType("application/json").body(payload, ObjectMapperType.GSON).when().post("http://example.com")`